# Superzised with bootstrap - 2 columns responsive layout

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, supersized

I would like to create something like this website http://krasotaiskusstva.com/ki/?theme=ananaswp

On the right site the Supersized background slider left the content. I have done this with a container on the left with col-md-8 and container fluid. But how could i possible do it that when i scale the browser both sides scale the same? at the moment the left side with the content get's much bigger than the right side with the slider. Does anyone have an idea how i could possible set this up?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep the same proportion use `col-xs-8` instead of `col-md-8`. When you go in a resolution under the 'medium size', bootstrap don't apply your 8-wide column style and probably use more or stack the two containers vertically.